# order of events when a window starts in Visual C++ MFC

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, events, visual-c++, mfc

suppose that I have a class derived from CWnd that have the event handler functions `OnPaint`,`OnCreate` and `OnSize`. As you know all of them are occured when the window starts but I want to see what is the order between them.
when I set a breakpoint in one of them, after ending the function, the control is not passed to another and goes to one of the MFC's built-in .cpp files for example `wincore.cpp`?
How can I understand the order? any links or teach me a way to prevent the control from going to MFC built-in classes?

Comment: I agree with edtheprogrammerguy's comment but for investigation purposes, you could always handle those events and trace.

Answer (score 5):

The order in which messages arrive is not fully defined and documented. However, some messages are ordered with respect to others. The MSDN explicitly states that [`WM_NCCREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632635.aspx) is sent prior to [`WM_CREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619.aspx). The documentation for `WM_CREATE` has a few more hints as far as the order is concerned (emphasis mine):

> Sent when an application requests that a window be created by calling the `CreateWindowEx` or `CreateWindow` function. (The message is **sent before the function returns**.) The window procedure of the new window receives this message after the window is created, but **before the window becomes visible**.

It should be immediately clear, that a window has to exist to receive additional messages. Consequently, the first [`WM_SIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646.aspx) will be sent after `WM_CREATE`. As for [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) it requires that a window is visible. Plus, it is a low priority message that is only generated if the message queue is empty.

During window creation the order is `WM_CREATE`, `WM_SIZE`, `WM_PAINT`.

If you are only interested in observing messages you can use a tool like Spy++ (spyxx.exe) that comes with Visual Studio. It can log arbitrary messages and gives you detailed information. If this is for educational purposes (as opposed to deducing behavior) it is a very helpful tool.

*Note to downvoters: If you feel this answer is inaccurate or needs improvement please leave a note to help future visitors.*

Comment: Note to downvoters: If you feel this answer is inaccurate or needs improvement please leave a note to help future visitors. ----- For toplevel windows first message is WM_GETMINMAXINFO, not WM_NCCREATE, but I am not downvoted. :)

Comment: @Xearinox I wasn't aware to have made any statement on what the first message is... I placed an order on some of them, relative to each other. And that is it.